# How do you layout columns of DIVs? (or, what am I doing wrong)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, first off, I am new at this so be gentle (please).  I am trying to layout multiple columns of divs.  Each div contains multiple images stacked vertically.  The images are all the same size.  Here is what I've come up with using jQuery:

```
var $columns= $('<div />', {
    css: {
        align: 'center', position: 'absolute',
        height: 125, width: '100%', left: 0, top: 355, zIndex: 10
    },
    id: 'columns',
    text: 'Towers'
}).appendTo('#mainDiv');

for (var c = 0; c < 6; ++c) {
    var $c = $('<div />', {
        css: {
            marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5,
            textAlign: 'center',
            top: 20, width: 20, zIndex: 20
        },
        id: 'c' + c
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        $c.append($('<img />', {
            css: {
                marginBottom: 0, zIndex: 30
            },
            id: 'c' + c + 'i' + i,
            src: 'image' + c + '.png'
        }));
    }

    $columns.append($c);
}
```

Each image is 17x11px.  When I run this I get 6 columns with 8 images vertically stacked.  But, the columns are all in a single column.  I want them side-by-side.  Is this just the totally wrong way to do it or am I at least close.

Extra credit: How do I make the images overlap each other by say 4px top to bottom?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: #Esteban - I would say current back to IE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<div>` is a block element so it has `display:block` by default; this means that it is as wide as its parent unless you assign it a specific width. I think what you want to do is use `inline-block` with `$c`:

```
var $c = $('<div />', {
    css: {
        display: 'inline-block',
        marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5,
        textAlign: 'center',
        zIndex: 20
    },
    id: 'c' + c
});
```

Setting `top` won't do anything for you as you haven't specified a `position`. If the images are 17x11 then you should say so:

```
$c.append($('<img />', {
    css: {
        marginBottom: 0, zIndex: 30
    },
    id: 'c' + c + 'i' + i,
    src: 'image' + c + '.png',
    width: 17,
    height: 11
}));
```

And if you want a bit of overlap, then set a negative top margin to push them up a bit and set `display: block` on the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/949ey/

Comment: thanks, this worked the best for me as I don't know how many columns I will have and I want them to be centered in mainDiv (though that is another question).

Comment: @Dave: You should also take Phelios's advice about using classes on your elements rather than all that inlined CSS: cleaner and more standard code.

Comment: and Phelios: Good advice.  I think its quicker to prototype this way (at least for me) but I plan to convert this all to CSS classes once it works

Answer (score 2):

Weird solution you got there, I'm torn between liking and hating it. Still, without giving your inner divs a position property, they'll default to `static` and top/left won't do anything.

Also, the idea behind CSS positioning is to have an outer element with position relative and inner elements with position absolute. Those inner elements will have absolute positioning relative to the parent div with position:relative.

```
var $columns= $('<div />', {
    css: {
        align: 'center', position: 'relative',
        height: 125, width: '100%', left: 0, top: 0, zIndex: 10
    },
    id: 'columns',
    text: 'Towers'
}).appendTo('#mainDiv');

for (var c = 0; c < 6; ++c) {
    var $c = $('<div />', {
        css: {
            marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5,
            textAlign: 'center',
            position: 'absolute', top: 20, left:15*c, 
            width: 20, zIndex: 20
        },
        id: 'c' + c
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        $c.append($('<img />', {
            css: {
                marginBottom: 0, zIndex: 30
            },
            id: 'c' + c + 'i' + i,
            src: 'image' + c + '.png'
        }));
    }

    $columns.append($c);
}
```

If you want images to overlap, you can use absolute positioning again on images. Consider you already loop through them:

```
css: {
    marginBottom: 0, zIndex: 30,
    position: 'absolute',
    left:0, top:15 * i
}
```

### Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/9Sdre/).

Comment: I'll suggest to use class on the `divs` instead of generating the css like this.

Comment: I believe you could make the images overlap with a negative margin top/bottom. Thats not always the best idea, I've seen it do some odd things. Just though I'd throw in an alternative to absolute positioned images